# How many zeros can holomorphic ftn f on D have, when k-th derivative of f is bounded away from zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

$D$ is an open connected domain. $f:D \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic in $D$.
$$ \Big{|}\frac{d^kf}{dz^k} \Big{|}> 1 \qquad \forall\;z\in D$$

Then, how can we bound the number of zeros of $f$ in terms of $k$ ?

Comment: I guess you need to find a curve $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$ such that $e^{i \theta}f(\gamma(t))$ is real and $f(\gamma(0)) = f(\gamma(1)) = 0$. In that case there is at least one zero of $f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ on $t \in (0,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not. Consider $D =$ unit disc, $f = (x-2)^M - 2^M$ for large $M$